# Astropy import error, 'Parent module not loaded'

Tags: python, importerror, astropy

I'm trying to run Astropy under Windows 7 CPython 2.7.5.
I had a fresh install from the binary available at the [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/astropy/0.2.3#downloads) but when I try to import I got a `SystemError: Parent module 'astropy' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`
However, if I try to import it again, the error changes to a `ImportError` that is a known issue related to system permissions [Astropy Known Issues](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/known_issues.html)

The problem is I installed everything system-wide using a admin account. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Here you can see the full trackback.

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 1.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. ?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features. %quickref -> Quick reference. help      -> Python's own help system. object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details. Using matplotlib backend: TkAgg

In [1]: import astropy Custom TB Handler failed, unregistering
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last) c:\python27\lib\site-packages\astropy\logger.py in ipy_exc_handler(ipyshell, ety pe, evalue, tb, tb_offset)
    270             def ipy_exc_handler(ipyshell, etype, evalue, tb, tb_offset=N one):
    271                 # First use our excepthook
--> 272                 self._excepthook(etype, evalue, tb)
    273
    274                 # Now also do IPython's traceback

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\astropy\logger.py in _excepthook(self, etype, valu e, traceback)
    220             self.error(message, extra={'origin': mod.__name__})
    221         else:
--> 222             self.error(message)
    223         self._excepthook_orig(etype, value, traceback)
    224

C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.pyc in error(self, msg, *args,
**kwargs)    1173         """    1174         if self.isEnabledFor(ERROR):
-> 1175             self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)    1176    1177     def exception(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):

C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.pyc in _log(self, level, msg, args, exc_info, e xtra)    1266                 exc_info = sys.exc_info()    1267         record = self.makeRecord(self.name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, e xc_info, func, extra)
-> 1268         self.handle(record)    1269    1270     def handle(self, record):

C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.pyc in handle(self, record)    1276   """    1277         if (not self.disabled) and self.filter(record):
-> 1278             self.callHandlers(record)    1279    1280     def addHandler(self, hdlr):

C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.pyc in callHandlers(self, record)    1316                 found = found + 1    1317                 if record.levelno >= hdlr.level:
-> 1318                     hdlr.handle(record)    1319             if not c.propagate:    1320                 c = None    #break out

C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.pyc in handle(self, record)
    747             self.acquire()
    748             try:
--> 749                 self.emit(record)
    750             finally:
    751                 self.release()

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\astropy\logger.py in
_stream_formatter(self, recor d)
    337             color_print(record.levelname, 'brown', end='')
    338         else:
--> 339             color_print(record.levelname, 'red', end='')
    340         print(": {0} [{1:s}]".format(record.msg, record.origin))
    341

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\astropy\utils\console.py in color_print(*args, **k wargs)
    228
    229     write = file.write
--> 230     if isatty(file) and USE_COLOR():
    231         for i in xrange(0, len(args), 2):
    232             msg = args[i]

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\astropy\config\configuration.py in
__call__(self)
    334
    335         #get the value from the relevant `configobj.ConfigObj` object
--> 336         sec = get_config(self.module)
    337         if self.name not in sec:
    338             self.set(self.defaultvalue)

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\astropy\config\configuration.py in get_config(pack ageormod, reload)
    400
    401     from .paths import get_config_dir
--> 402     from ..utils import find_current_module
    403
    404     if packageormod is None:

SystemError: Parent module 'astropy' not loaded, cannot perform relative import The original exception:

In [2]: import astropy
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-2-d192094ef7da> in <module>()
----> 1 import astropy

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\astropy\__init__.py in <module>()
    125 if not _ASTROPY_SETUP_:
    126     from .logger import _init_log
--> 127     from . import config
    128
    129     import os

ImportError: cannot import name config

In [3]:
```

More info:
This is a similar problem to the described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442572/error-message-when-importing-astropy-in-windows-8), but I don't want to use Canopy or Anaconda.

Comment: This is *probably* a duplicate of the question you linked to.  I've never been able to reproduce this, but I think it actually has to do with a failure to import one of the compiled modules on Windows (possibly due to a msvcrt mismatch or something of the like).

Would you mind closing this as a duplicate?  I'm reasonably certain that it is.

Comment: In fact I feel that this is really not even a question for SO so much as it is an issue that should be on Astropy's bug tracker since it must have something to do with the Windows builds on specific platforms.

Comment: @Iguananaut, that would be fine for me, but I don't have rep to close my question... But I manage to fix it by using the new binary from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#astropy
I posted it here since the workaround suggested on astropy github doesn't worked. I now believe the problem is in how the binary was built.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error message when importing astropy in Windows 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442572/error-message-when-importing-astropy-in-windows-8)